# Where to start with realtime log reader in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, telegram-bot

I am interested in developing a realtime log reader in Python that can send notifications via telegram bot.

I am interested in developing a realtime log reader in Python that can send notifications via telegram bot.
Basically I want to:

1. Read server log in realtime
2. Track it for specific errors
3. If condition of error is met, I want program to notify me and my
   team via telegram bot with specific message
4. If error is no longer appearing in log, I want program to notify me and my team via telegram bot with specific message

I don't know where to start. What libraries I should go through? Which technology(daemon for i.e) I should better use?